# Query isn't working - printing array value instead of using it withing the query

Tags: php

I'm not sure my question makes much sense so I will try my best to explain. Basically, I want the $_GET['quote_id'] to be a condition in the query but it is displaying on the web page instead, I'll post a picture as an example.

Code.php

```
<?php
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "quote");
  $query = "select * from `quote` where quote_id = '". $id = print_r($_GET['quote_id'])."'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>
```

[As you can see, it is displaying on the web page instead of being a part of the query which is my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9fOT.png)

Thanks for your help,

Comment: `print_r` actually outputs the variable it's applied to - that is, to the document, as you're seeing. Just get rid of that function call and it will work (but you'll be vulnerable SQL injection, so do some research on how to avoid that).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you used [print_r](http://php.net/print_r) (a function that prints human-readable information about a variable), this is why the output is showing on your page.

Try change to this, first dont attribute and use a variable at same, do only one thing at time for readability, second use [filter_input](http://php.net/filter_input) to sanitize your inputs or [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) attacks:

```
<?php

  $id = filter_input($_GET['quote_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "quote");
  $query = "select * from `quote` where quote_id = '". $id ."'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>
```